# submit button scroll to div and a bit more

Tags: javascript, php

Right now I have this pretty easy code

```
<h1 id="testpos">HEADLINE</h1>
<form method="post" action="#testpos">
```

However, since my horizontal menu bar is always fixed on top, I need it to scroll to the #testpos div + height of the menu bar (I know the height)

Any way to do this?

Comment: Thats quite the vague question without any real code attempts to go on. Are you using jquery? Are you using any jquery plugins? Looking for strictly vanilla js methods?

Comment: Sorry, im still quite a newbie and I can't use jquery yet so hopefully some way in js or php

Comment: You can use Jquery, it's very easy...

Comment: Jquery is actually a good thing for newbie's... it helps you get rolling and doing all manner of js goodness without dealing with a lot of the nittygritty. But yes, this can be done in vanilla javascript (since jquery is just a layer). It cannot really be done in PHP, since php just builds the page to be output.

Comment: Er actually... were you wanting smooth scrolling, or just anchor snapping? You wouldn't need any javascript to do this if you just want it to snap up to that `h1`. Just offset with css (see above duplicate link).

Comment: @EdKorket   thanks your solution worked!